# Flutter CircleAvatar Image changes on same file but does not change on screen

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a problem  where I choose a image and save it to a file.
Then the image displays after drawing the ui:

```
new CircleAvatar(
        minRadius: 50.0,
        maxRadius: 90.0,
        backgroundImage: AssetImage(_profilepic().path), 
       //new ExactAssetImage(_profilepic().path),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF6F6F6),
      )
```

But when I choose another image and write that image to  the same filename it after drawing it stays the same.
When I pop out of the page and go back it loads the image correctly.
I have tried to us imageCache.clear(); to refresh but that did not seem to work.

Comment: you simply have to rebuild your `CircleAvatar`, more [here](https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro)

Comment: thank you very helpfull!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that  you are not using a Stateful Widget so if you are using a Statless Widget change it to Stateful one  . 
If you are using a Stateful Widget you should rebuild you Circle Avatar using

```
setState(() { });
```